# Update Nested Object in Array in React Using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to change the status in the users array. I'm trying to update the status to 'Yes'. How can i be able to access its data without mutating the state?

Pls see this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-state-redux-62u80?file=/user.js)

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.user.isLoading);
  const users = useSelector(state => state.user.users);

  const onApprove = user => {
    dispatch(approveUser(user));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the state in the reducer without mutating try this:

```
    case 'YOUR_ACTION':
        return {
            ...state,
            users: state.users.map((user) =>
                user.id === action.userId
                    ? {
                          ...user,
                          status: 'yes', // or you could action.status
                      }
                    : user,
            ),
        }
```

I'm mapping over all `users`, then matching the user.id with the one sent through from the action and changing the status of it to `yes`. if it doesn't match, we simply return `user`

Comment: Thank you Red Baron

Answer (score 1):

Update the `approveUser` action to take and pass the `user`

```
export function approveUser(user) { // <-- receive user object
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: userConstants.APPROVE_USER_REQUEST
    });
    dispatch({
      type: userConstants.APPROVE_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        approved: "HAHAHHA"
      },
      user, // <-- pass user object
    });
    dispatch({
      type: userConstants.APPROVE_USER_FAILURE,
      payload: {}
    });
  };
}
```

Then update the reducer to spread update in. Use the received `user` object to map the new 'yes' status.

```
case userConstants.APPROVE_USER_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    users: state.users.map(user => user.id === action.user.id ? {
      ...user,
      status: 'yes',
    } : user)
  };
```

[image: Edit Update State Redux]